# Unity C# Image object not found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im following a tutorial on how to login using facebook sdk.
In the tutorial he does:

```
  Image User = UIFBAvatar.GetComponent<Image>();
```

the problem is that i can't find the objecttype image. what do i have to do to be able to use the Image-type as an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include this:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Comment: Thanks! That made it. Isn't it strange that i using UnityEngine; but that didn't include the using UnityEngine.UI; ?